# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected on xp.executenonquery()

Tags: c#, oledb

[datatypes in embedded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXdEU.png)

```
            OleDbCommand xp = new OleDbCommand("insert into personal_details (applicationid,firstname,middlename,lastname,gender,dob,nationality,emailid,phoneno) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", conn);
            xp.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("applicationid", flag);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", fname.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("middlename", mname.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", lname.Text);
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
                xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", radioButton1.Text);
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
                xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", radioButton2.Text);
            if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
                xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", radioButton3.Text);
            String date1 = date.Value.ToString() + "-" + month.SelectedItem.ToString() + "-" + year.Value.ToString();
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", date1);//add date
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("nationality", nationality.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("emailid", email.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("phoneno", mobile.Text);
            conn.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close(); flag++;
```

NOTE: using oracle 11g express database
I have tried a lot of permutations and combinations such as using [:,@,&]
Too frustrated. Kindly help.
There is no connection string error pretty sure about that

Comment: Is there a chance, that all three radiobuttons are not checked, and you do not add `@gender` parameter?

Comment: Which database do you use? It is MySQL? Please, add more information when you ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate values to be inserted before, your code seems to be correct, I've checked it.

```
create table personal_details (
applicationid number,
firstname nvarchar2(10),
middlename nvarchar2(10),
lastname nvarchar2(10),
gender nvarchar2(10),
dob date,
nationality nvarchar2(10),
emailid nvarchar2(10),
phoneno nvarchar2(10)
);
```

and in C#

```
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
    OleDbCommand xp = new OleDbCommand("insert into personal_details (applicationid,firstname,middlename,lastname,gender,dob,nationality,emailid,phoneno) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", conn);
    xp.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("applicationid", 1);
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", "1");
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("middlename", "1");
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", "1");
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", "1");
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", DateTime.Today);//add date
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("nationality", "1");
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("emailid", "1");
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("phoneno", "1");
    conn.Open();
    xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

inserted one row successfully.

Comment: As I mentioned, one row was successfully inserted.

Comment: Yes. The problem was with the date field. Thanks :)

Comment: I was entering the correct date format however in string. Just had to convert string to datetime type using DateTime dt=convert.ToDateTime(string).